# Generate Image in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

How do I generate an image in CakePHP? I want to make a stop smoking site and i want to be able to generate an image showing "how many packs" and "how many cigarettes" they have not smoked.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. are you asking how to render an image in cakephp?

Comment: You mean you want to actually edit an image? What exactly do you want to show in the image? A counter being updated? In that case you can just create a div with an image background and have the text value updated.

Comment: @gvLearner - Yes. Let's say I have an image of a single cigarette, or a single pack. How can I add that same image multiple times to create a larger image.

Comment: @Jack No, not a counter but an actual image.

Comment: A single cigarette image? Echo it multiple times, side by side? Why do you want to merge them together into one image?

Answer (score 0):

Copy your image to `app\webroot\img` directory

eg: assume `cigarette.png` file is in the `app\webroot\img` directory. you can render that image in the view file as follows.
Then in the view file you can add the following code to display image.
    `<?php echo $this->Html->image('cigarette.png'); ?>`

If you want to show this image multiple times copy and paste it as much as you want.